# htaccess and php app navigation

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller

I'm getting crazy with a little problem on my simple web app. I made a simple calendar app with PHP, following MVC pattern.

Dirs structure is like:

```
calendar (root)
    -- app/
        -- controllers/
        -- core/
        -- models/
        -- views/
        init.php
    -- public/
        -- css/
        -- scripts/
        -- others dirs...
        -- .htaccess
        -- index.php
```

Every request are made like:

```
/calendar/public/[controller_name]/[controller_method]/[extra_params]
```

eg: `calendar/public/home/all_events`: call `all_events` method of `Home` class and then display with right view.

In each `view.php` I made link/button/etc with classic anchor, using `href` value like:

```html
<a href="[controller_name]/[method_name]">...</a>
```

ex. `href="booking/room"` in order to call the controller for booking and specify what (room).

Everything seems works fine, but only locally.

When I try to put it on server all links don't work, causing a 404 page not found.

I'm trying to put it into an existing website made with Joomla. every request  goes to a specific directory called `sitename.com/`, where there are all Joomla files plus my directory with the app.

There, I can just reach the app home page (default) but every link is not working.

I tried everything, but nothing seems to work.

I think the issue is in Apache configuration (or `.htaccess`). It die with a 404 page not found error and my `index.php` is never called.

This is my htaccess:

```bash
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /sitename.com/calendar/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Or maybe I can't link pages with in that way, but how can I call specific controller/method from html?

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled on your server? Go to SSH and type these two commands to enable it `sudo a2enmod rewrite;service apache2 restart;`

Comment: By the way, best way to implement your pattern is to configure a virtual host that points to the public folder..

Comment: I don't have permission to restart Apache, however mod_rewrite should be enabled, not sure how to use it. I'm trying different configs but nothing is working. 

What is a virtual host and how can I use it? Is it a service offered by hosting? I have a economic plan (it's a very little website and the app will be used by a little group of registered users).

Comment: You need to be the root. Serious people work on Dedicated and VPS servers ;)

Comment: for root, type `sudo -i`

Comment: It's a shared server guys, I cannot restart server and put down other sites lol. Maybe a "graceful" restart... but this will not fix my problem, mod_rewrite module is alredy enabled! How can I solve this problem in your opinion? I'm trying to use rewriteRule to "catch" url that contain "calendar/public" and then redirect them on right directory, but it's not working...